# Can I ask about copyright here?

Tags: reference-request, notation

I don't know it is okay if I post about copyright here. If there is any problem, please leave a comment. I will delete this post. Thank you.

---

I am a graduate student studying engineering and mathematics.

I sometimes feel regret not keeping my study notes or summaries.

Thus, from now on, I decided to sum up what I learned and what I will learn (for example, electric circuit, communication theory, real analysis, probability theory, ...)

I want to make my own blog and to share my summaries and to copy some contents of textbooks (e.g. theorem, lemma, corollary and their proofs)

It is totally non-commercial purpose. Just, I want to re-study and to help some students who have a difficulty reading English textbooks.

However, I am worried about the copyright.

---

1. **Summary** is surely based on textbook, but I will rearrange into my style.
2. **Theorem** and **its proof** will be typed from my finger, but its contents are totally based on textbook. I don't have capability of prove them for myself.
3. Exercises or problems will be based on some solutions-pdf wandering on internet.

---

Is it illegal to post **summary, copy theorems and their proofs, and exercise's solution**?

Comment: 1. I don't think there are copyright issues as far as you reference (in general) where are you taking the material from. 2. I think your question should be moved to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ since it is not a mathematical question, but rather a moral/practical question. You will probably even find better answers there.

Comment: Perhaps the academia stack exchange would be better suited for this type of question? It's related to mathematics, surely, but the main point is concerning academic ethics. http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Wore meta is for questions about stackexchange itself. So "can I ask about copyright here" is appropriate for meta, but "is the kind of blog I'm thinking of on shaky legal ground" is not.

Comment: By general the soul of mathematicians are not going to feel bad if you "copy" some content if you leave the credit, indeed the is a lot of free material in the net about maths! Anyway I think that is better re-writing all and not only copy-paste.

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you very much. I will never scan or copy. Just I want to copy of concept and process of solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copyright is very rarely an issue in mathematics, as long as proper attribution is given. It would be absurd to try to copyright a theorem, insofar as someone else could rediscover it for themselves, and often someone else does. If you're duplicating large portions of a published textbook to the open Internet, that could in principle be a copyright violation, just as it would if you uploaded a scan of an entire textbook. Presumably you won't be duplicating huge chunks, though, so there will be no problem.

So you should just cite what textbook you're referencing, and which sections. If you're copying ideas from PDFs you find online, you should also acknowledge the author to whatever extent you can. That's more about being polite than about legality, since if someone's posted their solutions freely online, they're unlikely to sue you for using them!

Comment: The law (inasmuch as I have ever been told) is that you need author/publisher permission if you are duplicating the lesser of: 10% of the book; or an entire chapter of the book. Outside of this, cite your sources and give credit, and it won't pose an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the more precise answer!

Comment: @NicholasStull That is incorrect. Fair use does partly depend on how much you copied, but not in any cut and dried fashion like a specific percentage. Fair use will look at all four factors ( https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/ ) as a whole...there are cases where very small portions were deemed not fair use, and cases where very large portions or even the entire work were deemed as being fair use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When I added this comment (some 5 years ago now), it was my understanding of the law as pertained to the university I was (at the time) employed by. As it turns out, they were playing fast and loose with the rules, and so the information I was given was both incorrect and left the employees who did follow their guidance exposed to civil action by publishers/authors. Thanks for the link clarifying the matter.